# Declaring Thread syntax understanding

Tags: c#, syntax

While reading a book named "Programming in C#", I've came across a syntax that I fail to understand :

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    new Thread( () =>
         {
            for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
            {
                _field++;
                Console.WriteLine("Thread A : {0}", _field);
            }

         }).Start();  
}
```

What does " () => " refers to, and what constructor is called ? I tried to google it but "() =>" is kinda hard to search on google.

Comment: It's a lambda expression - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397687.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a lambda expression, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397687.aspx) for the docs.

More specifically, it is an anonymous function. The `Thread` constructor requires a function that is called when the thread starts. Rather than creating a function for re-use (`void ThreadFunc() { ... }`), an anonymous function is declared in-line.

Comment: So if "()" means "No argument", if I needed a string as argument, would i write  "New Thread( (string s) => {...} )" ?

Comment: Yes. And if you want a `string` and an `int`, you can do this: `(int x, string s) => s.Length > x`. Have a read through the docs, these examples are on that exact page.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know C# but this looks like an anonymous function. That is the Thread Object will run this function once start is called, on a seperate thread.

EDIT: its called anonymous because it has no name, also () => {} are 'arguments' => 'fun-body'

Answer (score 0):

`() => ...` just means that it is the lambda expression that  takes no parameters. It is same as the following

**without parameter:**

```
void MyWork() // This is your class constructor
{
    for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
        {
            _field++;
            Console.WriteLine("Thread A : {0}", _field);
        }
}



new Thread(MyWork).Start();
```

**With Parameter:**

```
void MyWork(int _number) // This is your class constructor
{
    for(int x = 0; x < _number; x++)
        {
            _field++;
            Console.WriteLine("Thread A : {0}", _field);
        }
}



new Thread(() => MyWork(10)).Start();
```

Comment: If i want to use an anonymous function which uses 2 parameters, a string and an int, how would I write it ?

Comment: It's better to use delegate